# Password migration from Drupal to Yii

Tags: drupal, yii

Has anyone already migrate a site from Drupal to Yii?
Is there some code in Yii that can implement the Drupal encryption and salt for user password?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have, but not to YII. Its not a big deal. You can use the same salt and encryption in YII as well (easier since both are PHP based).

Check these two pages:
http://www.yiiframework.com/wiki/425
https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes!password.inc/function/user_hash_password/7

Answer (score 1):

Thanks Amar, I follow your links and
I create the YII functions for migrating from drupal7.

They work for me and I could save 1 working hour to someone (not more I guess)

I put all of them in 
class UserIdentity extends CUserIdentity

and use this way in

```
..
  } else if (self::user_check_password($this->password, $users->password) ) {
.. 
in   public function authenticate()

  private function user_check_password($password, $registered_password) {
    if (substr($registered_password, 0, 2) == 'U$') {
      // This may be an updated password from user_update_7000(). Such hashes
      // have 'U' added as the first character and need an extra md5().
      $stored_hash = substr($registered_password, 1);
      $password = md5($password);
    }
    else {
      $stored_hash = $registered_password;
    }

    $type = substr($stored_hash, 0, 3);
    switch ($type) {
      case '$S$':
        // A normal Drupal 7 password using sha512.
        $hash = self::_password_crypt('sha512', $password, $stored_hash);
        break;
      case '$H$':
        // phpBB3 uses "$H$" for the same thing as "$P$".
      case '$P$':
        // A phpass password generated using md5.  This is an
        // imported password or from an earlier Drupal version.
        $hash = self::_password_crypt('md5', $password, $stored_hash);
        break;
      default:
        return FALSE;
    }
    return ($hash && $stored_hash == $hash);
  }

  private function user_hash_password($password) {
    return self::_password_crypt('sha512', $password, self::_password_generate_salt(15));
  }

  private function _password_crypt($algo, $password, $setting) {
    // The first 12 characters of an existing hash are its setting string.
    $setting = substr($setting, 0, 12);

    if ($setting[0] != '$' || $setting[2] != '$') {
      return FALSE;
    }
    $count_log2 = self::_password_get_count_log2($setting);
    // Hashes may be imported from elsewhere, so we allow != DRUPAL_HASH_COUNT
    if ($count_log2 < 7 || $count_log2 > 30) {
      return FALSE;
    }
    $salt = substr($setting, 4, 8);
    // Hashes must have an 8 character salt.
    if (strlen($salt) != 8) {
      return FALSE;
    }

    // Convert the base 2 logarithm into an integer.
    $count = 1 << $count_log2;

    // We rely on the hash() function being available in PHP 5.2+.
    $hash = hash($algo, $salt . $password, TRUE);
    do {
      $hash = hash($algo, $hash . $password, TRUE);
    } while (--$count);

    $len = strlen($hash);
    $output = $setting . self::_password_base64_encode($hash, $len);
    // _password_base64_encode() of a 16 byte MD5 will always be 22 characters.
    // _password_base64_encode() of a 64 byte sha512 will always be 86 characters.
    $expected = 12 + ceil((8 * $len) / 6);
    return (strlen($output) == $expected) ? substr($output, 0, 55) : FALSE;
  }

  private function _password_generate_salt($count_log2) {
    $output = '$S$';
    // Ensure that $count_log2 is within set bounds.
    $count_log2 = self::_password_enforce_log2_boundaries($count_log2);
    // We encode the final log2 iteration count in base 64.
    $itoa64 = self::_password_itoa64();
    $output .= $itoa64[$count_log2];
    // 6 bytes is the standard salt for a portable phpass hash.
    $output .= self::_password_base64_encode(self::drupal_random_bytes(6), 6);
    return $output;
  }

  private function _password_enforce_log2_boundaries($count_log2) {
    if ($count_log2 < 7) {
      return 7;
    }
    elseif ($count_log2 > 30) {
      return 30;
    }

    return (int) $count_log2;
  }

  private function _password_itoa64() {
    return './0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz';
  }

  private function _password_base64_encode($input, $count) {
    $output = '';
    $i = 0;
    $itoa64 = self::_password_itoa64();
    do {
      $value = ord($input[$i++]);
      $output .= $itoa64[$value & 0x3f];
      if ($i < $count) {
        $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 8;
      }
      $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 6) & 0x3f];
      if ($i++ >= $count) {
        break;
      }
      if ($i < $count) {
        $value |= ord($input[$i]) << 16;
      }
      $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 12) & 0x3f];
      if ($i++ >= $count) {
        break;
      }
      $output .= $itoa64[($value >> 18) & 0x3f];
    } while ($i < $count);

    return $output;
  }

  private function drupal_random_bytes($count) {
    // $random_state does not use drupal_static as it stores random bytes.
    static $random_state, $bytes, $has_openssl;

    $missing_bytes = $count - strlen($bytes);

    if ($missing_bytes > 0) {
      // PHP versions prior 5.3.4 experienced openssl_random_pseudo_bytes()
      // locking on Windows and rendered it unusable.
      if (!isset($has_openssl)) {
        $has_openssl = version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.4', '>=') && function_exists('openssl_random_pseudo_bytes');
      }

      // openssl_random_pseudo_bytes() will find entropy in a system-dependent
      // way.
      if ($has_openssl) {
        $bytes .= openssl_random_pseudo_bytes($missing_bytes);
      }

      // Else, read directly from /dev/urandom, which is available on many *nix
      // systems and is considered cryptographically secure.
      elseif ($fh = @fopen('/dev/urandom', 'rb')) {
        // PHP only performs buffered reads, so in reality it will always read
        // at least 4096 bytes. Thus, it costs nothing extra to read and store
        // that much so as to speed any additional invocations.
        $bytes .= fread($fh, max(4096, $missing_bytes));
        fclose($fh);
      }

      // If we couldn't get enough entropy, this simple hash-based PRNG will
      // generate a good set of pseudo-random bytes on any system.
      // Note that it may be important that our $random_state is passed
      // through hash() prior to being rolled into $output, that the two hash()
      // invocations are different, and that the extra input into the first one -
      // the microtime() - is prepended rather than appended. This is to avoid
      // directly leaking $random_state via the $output stream, which could
      // allow for trivial prediction of further "random" numbers.
      if (strlen($bytes) < $count) {
        // Initialize on the first call. The contents of $_SERVER includes a mix of
        // user-specific and system information that varies a little with each page.
        if (!isset($random_state)) {
          $random_state = print_r($_SERVER, TRUE);
          if (function_exists('getmypid')) {
            // Further initialize with the somewhat random PHP process ID.
            $random_state .= getmypid();
          }
          $bytes = '';
        }

        do {
          $random_state = hash('sha256', microtime() . mt_rand() . $random_state);
          $bytes .= hash('sha256', mt_rand() . $random_state, TRUE);
        } while (strlen($bytes) < $count);
      }
    }
    $output = substr($bytes, 0, $count);
    $bytes = substr($bytes, $count);
    return $output;
  }

  private function _password_get_count_log2($setting) {
    $itoa64 = self::_password_itoa64();
    return strpos($itoa64, $setting[3]);
  }
```